# Python notation when casting a list

Tags: python, syntax, casting

Why do I have to enclose the following code in brackets? Why is there a difference between square and round brackets?

```
>>> a= [1,2,3]
>>> (str(x) for x in a)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10ade8af0>
>>> [str(x) for x in a]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: `()` makes a generator, `[]` a list.

Comment: Isn't the output clear enough? The first one is a generator expression. Just search for this term, you will sure get lot of questions talking about this.

Comment: Python doesn't use casting. Some types support creating a new instance using an object of a different type (l = list("foo"), e.g.), but that is different from treating an object of type A as if it were an object of type B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(str(x) for x in a)` is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

`[str(x) for x in a]` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Here's a [discussion of the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension), from the archives.